# sql many to one

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день.
Имеются следующие таблицы

LIST

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | first  |
+----+--------+
| 2  | second |
+----+--------+
```

PLACE

```
+----+---------+------+
| id | list_id | summ |
+----+---------+------+
| 1  | 1       | 100  |
+----+---------+------+
| 2  | 1       | 200  |
+----+---------+------+
```

Мне нужно выбрать все поля из таблицы `LIST`, чтобы в таблице было название `LIST` и сумма `PLACE`. Примерно таблица должна получиться такая

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | name   | summ |
+----+--------+------+
| 1  | first  | 300  |
+----+--------+------+
| 2  | second | 0    |
+----+--------+------+
```

Ума не приложу как это сделать, ведь если делать выборку из `PLACE`, то туда не попадут те `LIST`, у которых нету `PLACE`. А иначе я не представляю как суммировать `PLACE.summ`

Comment: Left join + Group by решают проблему.
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, sum(p.summ) AS summ FROM LIST AS l
LEFT JOIN PLACE AS p ON l.id=p.list_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло `union`
В данном примере запрос будет следующим

```
# первый запрос - делаем выборку всех LIST в которых есть PLACE

(SELECT l.id, l.name, SUM(p.summ) as summ FROM place p 
left join list l on l.id = p.list_id
group by l.id)

union

# второй запрос - делаем выборку всех LIST в которых нет PLACE и задаем summ = 0

(SELECT l.id, l.name, 0 as summ FROM list l 
left outer join place p on l.id = p.list_id 
where p.id is null)
```

Comment: Вы все усложняете. left join и так делает то что вам нужно. Вы просто перепутали местами таблицы в left join. Та таблица в которой есть все записи должна быть слева т.е. первой. Либо можно использовать right join, у которого обязательная таблица справа: `SELECT l.id, l.name, coalesce(SUM(p.summ),0) as summ FROM place p 
RIGHT join list l on l.id = p.list_id
group by l.id`